# Check the keys in the map matching with the List content in Java

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List` of `Strings` and a `Map`. Every key in the map needs to present in the list else I need to throw an exception. As of now I am looping the list and checking the key and throw exception if the map doesn't contains the key. Below is the sample code is what I am doing.  IS there any other way in **Java8** we can do it in one line or something using `streams` and `filters` ?

And also the contents in the list and keys in the map should match. That I am already handling in the separate if condition.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> ll = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
        ll.add("a");
        ll.add("b");
        ll.add("d");

        m.put("a", 1);
        m.put("b", 1);
        m.put("c", 1);

        if(ll.size() != m.size){
       System.out.println("Throw Exception");
         }

        for(String s : ll) {

            if(!m.containsKey(s)) {
                System.out.println("Throw Exception");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are saying different things in your question and in your code. In your question you said you want to check if every key is in the list, but in the code, you are checking if everything in the list is present in the map.

Comment: How about this `ll.stream().filter(s -> !m.containsKey(s)).forEach(s -> {
            throw new RuntimeException("Not found");
        });
`?

Comment: @Sweeper Sorry , I will modify the question. Technically, the contents in the list and keys in the map should match.

Comment: If they really need to match, then test something like `m.keySet().equals(new HashSet<>(ll))`. Or maybe keep the required keys in a set in the first place.

Comment: @sparker Seems like what you are expecting your code does is not what it actually is doing. Maybe think about it and rephrase the question to clear out the doubt.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Every key in the map needs to present in the list else I need to throw
>   an exception

You could do it using [`Stream.anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) and iterating on the `keyset` of the map instead as (variable names updated for readability purpose) :

```
if(map.keySet().stream().anyMatch(key -> !list.contains(key))) {
    throw new CustomException("");
}
```

Better and as simple as it gets, use [`List.containsAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)) :

```
if(!list.containsAll(map.keySet())) {
    throw new CustomException("");
}
```

**Important**: If you can trade for `O(n)` space to reduce the runtime complexity, you can create a `HashSet` out of your `List` and then perform the lookups. It would reduce the runtime complexity from `O(n^2)` to `O(n)` and the implementation would look like:

```
Set<String> allUniqueElementsInList = new HashSet<>(list);
if(!allUniqueElementsInList.containsAll(map.keySet())) {
    throw new CustomException("");
}
```

Comment: Or `if(! map.keySet().stream().allMatch(list::contains))`, but of course, `if(!list.containsAll(map.keySet()))` is the canonical solution.

Answer (score 3):

We can try adding the list to a set, then comparing that set with the keyset from your hashmap:

```
List<String> ll = new ArrayList<>();
ll.add("a");
ll.add("b");
ll.add("d");

Map<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put("a", 1);
m.put("b", 1);
m.put("c", 1);

Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(ll);

if (Objects.equals(set, m.keySet())) {
    System.out.println("sets match");
}
else {
    System.out.println("sets do not match");
}
```

Comment: I think OP is looking for an answer wrt to java-8 *(something using streams and filters)* here.

Comment: @NicholasK well there is nothing in the code here, that doesn't work with java8., right? But yeah the throwing of exception is definitely missing and also an unwanted creation of Set which doesn't seem to be required for the purpose of OP.

Comment: Ummm... `if (...m.keySet() == null ...)` ... what is that? The `keySet` can never be `null`, and in any case: the comparison of the `size()` and the `containsAll` call boil down to a simple `if (Objects.equals(m.keySet(), set)) ` ...

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the following :-

```
m.keySet().stream().filter(e -> !ll.contains(e))
                   .findAny()
                   .ifPresent(e -> throwException("Key Not found : " + e));
```

And define the *throwException* method below :

```
public static void throwException(String msg) {
    throw new RuntimeException(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change your existing code to -

```
if(!m.keySet().containsAll(ll)) {
    System.out.println("Throws Exception");
}
```

This will solve your problem. :)

Comment: This logic has a problem.  Should the hashmap's keyset contain _extra_ items, your code would still return true.  Also, if `null` on both sides of the comparison means equal, then you would have to cover that case as well.

Comment: @p.bansal - The [same check performed in reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54141925/1746118) was what OP is mostly trying to look forward to.

Comment: @nullpointer This matches the OP’s code but not the text in the question, which requests the reverse. So +1 from me on this answer. But then the OP said in comments that the map keys must match the list, a yet again different check. (Sigh.)

Comment: @StuartMarks well, if they must match, I’d use `if(m.size() != ll.size() || !m.keySet().containsAll(ll))`, as I suppose, `m.keySet().containsAll(ll)` is potentially faster than `ll.containsAll(m.keySet())`…

Comment: @Holger At the time this answer was written, it matched the code in the question. The OP subsequently changed the requirements.

Comment: @StuartMarks I know; you already explained the inconsistency in your comment. So I was saying *if they must match* (the variant that was stated in a comment), I’d suggest that solution. By the time I wrote that comment, I even hadn’t noticed the last edit on the question…

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ((ll == null && m == null) ||                            // if both are null
   ((ll.size() == m.size() && m.keySet().containsAll(ll)))  // or contain the same elements
) {
    System.out.println("Collections contain the same elements");
} else {
    throw new CustomException("Collections don't match!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

```
    if (ll  .parallelStream()
            .filter(v -> !m.containsKey(v)) // Filter alle values not contained in the map
            .count() == 0) { // If no values are left then every key was present
        // do something
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("hello");
    }
```

Just wanted to show a different approach